# Best way to alert user

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a database with a table called userbadges . All users have all badges at level 0 "locked" (greyed out) . They can unlock it at level 1 , all the way to level 3. Each level is worth points.

```
userbadges {user_id,badge_id,level,score,seen}
```

What would be the best way for me to alert the user that they

- a) have unlocked a new badge
- b) have leveled up a badge

I have this code , but it doesn't seem right. It counts the number of new badges ():

```
function countNewBadges() {
        require "connect.php"; 

    $newbadges = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT users.studentid, individualbadges.badgename, ub.level, count(ub.seen) as total FROM userbadges ub
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = ub.user_id
INNER JOIN individualbadges ON individualbadges.id = ub.badge_id
WHERE studentid = '".$_SESSION["studentid"]."' && seen=0 && level!=0")  or die(mysqli_error($connection));

  while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($newbadges)) {

echo $data['total'];


  }
}
```

I also have code to set the seen field of the badges table to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a messaging system: Create a table message with text, title. (for every message you have or dynamicly) Then make a table user_has_message where you got the 2 Keys to join, and a boolean if read.

With a simple `Select * from user JOIN user_has_message on ... and iduser = ... JOIN  message on ... where read = false` you get all your alerts/Messages for a specified user.

**EDIT:** Now you can simply add an entry to `user_has_entry`, in which you specify which `user` should get which `message`.

Now you have much possibilities: add the date with default NOW(), to know when the message occoured, give the user the possibility to delete this message (what only deletes the entry on the `user_has_message`), add tho option to mark a message as unread, etc etc ...

Shure you can also use those messages for other things like a Welcome-Message etc. Or add a cronjob to send an email to the users with open messages older than 5 days. Or even implement a chat-system...

Comment: Im finding it difficult to understand this (its one of those days).  So a table with messages (you have unlocked this badge or this badge has leveled up ) and then user has massage table where it has id,user_id,message_id,read. The mysql query is what's stumping me . Wouldn't i need a trigger to tell the database that a user has unlocked a badge or leveled up and then display the correct message?

Comment: Yes. when you give a badge/leveled up, you add a entry to `user_has_entry`, in which you specify which user got which message.

Comment: But do not make a trigger on the database, send the message on the badge_unlocked()-function.